# Anyway to re-use an ItemMoveCallback class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there an ideal way to be able to re-use the ItemMoveCallback class I have created, that extends ItemTouchHelper, to be able to handle drag-drop for the recycler views in my application? I have several recycler views, some of which take different ViewHolders. The callback code is below:

```
public class ItemMoveCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private final ItemTouchHelperContract mAdapter;

public ItemMoveCallback(ItemTouchHelperContract adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

}

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    mAdapter.onRowMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {

        // Check for instance of adapter type here
        if (viewHolder instanceof PostListAdapter.ViewHolder) {
            PostListAdapter.ViewHolder myViewHolder=
                    (PostListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder;
            mAdapter.onRowSelected(myViewHolder);
        }
    }

    super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

    // Check for instance of adapter type here
    if (viewHolder instanceof PostListAdapter.ViewHolder) {
        PostListAdapter.ViewHolder myViewHolder=
                (PostListAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        mAdapter.onRowClear(myViewHolder);
    }
}

public interface ItemTouchHelperContract {
    void onRowMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition);
    void onRowSelected(PostListAdapter.ViewHolder myViewHolder);
    void onRowClear(PostListAdapter.ViewHolder myViewHolder);
}}
```

I was thinking of replacing the particular adapter parameter type with RecyclerView.ViewHolder instead of the actual adapter's view holder (as it extends from that type originally), that way I'd be able to use multiple adapters and check for instance types in the above functions, but it wasn't working out as expected.

Thanks everyone!!

**Edit:**

I end up with this in the PostListAdapter once trying the Abstract way though not able to access the fields created in the ViewHolder inside of the adapter (that extends AbstractViewHolder).

```
 @Override
public void onRowSelected(AbstractViewHolder myViewHolder) {
    // Can't access this way
    // myViewHolder.cardViewLayout.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    // wants me to find the views again
    myViewHolder.itemView.findViewById();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating another interface (or abstract superclass) that your view holders can implement. Then instead doing this:

```
if (viewHolder instanceof PostListAdapter.ViewHolder) { ... }
```

you can do this:

```
if (viewHolder instanceof MyViewHolderInterface) { ... }
```

and replace all the types in your `ItemTouchHelperContract` as so:

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperContract {

    void onRowMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition);
    void onRowSelected(MyViewHolderInterface myViewHolder);
    void onRowClear(MyViewHolderInterface myViewHolder);
}
```

---

You could even take this a step further to ensure a bit more safety and create base classes for both your adapter and view holders:

```
abstract class AbstractAdapter<T extends AbstractAdapter.AbstractViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {

    static abstract class AbstractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ...
    }
}
```

This would remove the need for casting in your `ItemMoveCallback`.

Comment: That would be through RecyclerView.ViewHolder right? So currently, for `onRowSelected` for example, using the `PostListAdapter.ViewHolder` as the function param allows me to use the ViewHolder I defined there with its fields for the various parts in that item view. When I change the param to RecyclerView.ViewHolder, and use the `myViewHolder` object within that overridden onRowSelected, I don't have the fields of my custom ViewHolder anymore. It gives me the original `myViewHolder.itemView` scope where I can use findViewById. Was there a way to work around that?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Added a slightly better method that I might consider if appropriate.

Comment: Definitely something worth considering. If I were to go with the base classes for the adapter and view holders, would I still need a ViewHolderInterface or would I then extend from the abstract class, and change the params in `ItemTouchHelperContract` to the abstract?

Comment: & then extend the PostListAdapter by AbstractAdapter if I can recall correctly?

Comment: Yes exactly that, the `ViewHolderInterface` can forgotten about and instead use `AbstractViewHolder` to represent your shared view model logic.

Comment: Edited my original post with this addition, I still end up not being able to access the particular fields created like in the first comment. Definitely possible I'm setting it up wrong though

Comment: Moved this to a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229840/discussion-between-hunter-and-henry-twist